# Hiding controller name and action name in the URL of an asp.net MVC app

Tags: url, model-view-controller

My ASP.net MVC application is hosted under the URL`http://10.80.9.25/mydomain/`.
When I access the app in my browser, the URL is shown as 
`http://10.80.9.25/mydomain/mycontroller`.
I don't want `mycontroller` name to be displayed in the URL. I want the URL to always just be `http://10.80.9.25/mydomain/` irrespective of the controller or action. Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to do custom routing in which case I would just follow [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). But I'm surprised you want to not display the controller or action names as how would a user know where they are on your site? Is it a one page app? Either way best of luck

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can hiding controller name and action name in the URL of an asp.net MVC 
please check following screenshots...

In this use custom routes after this we can access [app with name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jwwX.png) and [url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVdCG.png) but name and url is always same.
 Please check image

I Hope this post helpful.